# Use two providers for the same class with different generic typing in Angular Jasmine Tests

Tags: angular, redux, jasmine

I am trying to create two distinct mock providers and spys for classes that are injected into my component. The dependencies are the same class but use a different typing, using generics.

```
constructor(
private readonly languageStore: Store<fromLanguageStore.LanguageState>,
private readonly userStore: Store<fromUserStore.UserState>) {}
```

component.ts

I have tried the below;

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: Store<fromLangaugeStore.LanguageState>,
      useValue: languageStoreMock
    },
    {
      provide: Store<fromUserStore.UserState>,
      useValue: userStoreMock
    }
  ]
```

component.spec.ts

In the spec file, it is not possible to do the above. I have also tried to use one provider and use a spyOn like so;

```
spyOn(storeMock, 'pipe').and.callFake((func) => {
  //
})
```

but what is passed into the method is select() function from `'@ngrx/store'` and I can't see how to switch what is returned by the fake based on the method, as they both pass select, but the argument is different i.e.

```
this.languageStore.pipe(select(fromLanguageStore.getLanguageContext))
this.userStore.pipe(select(fromUserStore.getUserContext))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to me that you're injecting the `Store` twice in your component. I would just inject it once like so:

```
constructor(
private readonly store: Store<fromLanguageStore.LanguageState | fromUserStore.UserState>) {}
```

The store is one database and anytime you need the `languageState`, you can do:

```
languageState$ = this.store.select(....); // select the language state from the store
userState$ = this.store.select(....); // select the user state from the store
```

This way, you will only have to create the mock for the `Store` once.

Edit

I provide the store and do integration testing to mock different slices of the store.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, BookListComponent, BookCollectionComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      books: booksReducer,
      collection: collectionReducer,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [GoogleBooksService],
}).compileComponents();
 
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
store = TestBed.inject(Store);  // get a handle on the store
store.dispatch(new SetUsers(...)); // put the users you want in the ...
store.dispatch(new SetLanguage(...)); // put the language state you want in the ... // after doing the above lines, your store should be populated with what you want
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Check out this [link](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#integration-testing).

Comment: Consider a method in the component that uses both states, how would you mock that? I get what you have done with the DI etc.